# ReferenceError: window is not defined Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

global.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// javascript import for when you're importing the css directly in your javascript
import "vue-navigation-bar/dist/vue-navigation-bar.css";

// import the library
import VueNavigationBar from "vue-navigation-bar";

Vue.component("vue-navigation-bar", VueNavigationBar);
```

nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/global.js', ssr: false }
  ],
```

Error

```
window is not defined
```

I have tried all the possible solutions in nuxtjs documentation still getting same error.
Thanks!

Comment: where do you call your importet library

Comment: In `index.vue`.

Comment: i mena how are you using it

Comment: `​<​template​>​
  ​<​vue-navigation-bar​ :​options​=​"​navbarOptions​" /​>​
​<​/​template​>​`

Comment: did you tried it to wrap in an `<client-only></client-only>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to wrap it in `<client-only>`

```
​<​template​>
   <client-only>
      <​vue-navigation-bar​ :​options​=​"​navbarOptions​" /​>
   </client-only>​​
<​/​template​>
```